# How to implement User system for job board (I need employers to be able to register and create posts)?

Tags: django, django-users

I am creating a job board where users can search a zip code and see jobs in their area. I have the following models.py:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 10)


class Job(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete = "models.CASCADE") #when the referenced object is deleted, also delete the objects that have references to it.
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        zip_code = self.business.zip_code
        super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

To use the website to look for jobs, you do not have to sign in. However, I obviously need employer's to be able to create an account so that they can register a business and post jobs for said business. I am not sure how to approach this and have seen many different ways to go about it online. Should I have the `Business` model extend the `User` model as such:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other fields...
```

and then when an employer registers show a form that includes the `User` fields as well as the `Business` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is only to do this and you're just starting, I would say easiest would be just extending the User model as pointed out in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project).

But most probably you rather need an Employee model (for you may have other types of users!?). Such an Employee model could have a one-to-one relation with the User model for example.

[Here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) is an overview of the options for extending the User model for different needs.

p.s. You need not store the zip-code in the Job model (nor override save for that matter). You can access it via the Foreign Key relation. So if job is a Job object: `job.business.zip_code` will get you the zip_code